# Nested Routing with url param is not working in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm setting up nested routes within React-router-dom (v5.0.1), but it (route `/primary/:id`) is not working whenever I try and access one of the nested routes.

Nested route looks like..

```
const id = ({match}) =>  (
    <div>
        with id {match.params.id}
    </div>
)

const primary = ({match}) => (
    <div>
        This is the Primary route
        <br/>
        <Link to='/primary/one'>Primary with id</Link>
        <Route path='/primary/:id' component={id} />
    </div>
)
```

I cannot access the *id* component.
I call the primary component in *Routes* component.

```js
const Routes = () => {
    return(
        <Router>
            <Route exact path='/' component={main} />
            <Route exact path='/primary' component={primary} />    
        </Router>
    )
}
```

And *Routes* are called in *App* component as follows.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define two `Routes` for `primary` and `id` components as follows.

```js
const id = () =>  (
    <div>
        with id {props.id}
    </div>
)

const primary = () => (
    <div>
        This is the Primary route
        <br/>
        {
          props.match.params.id ? 
            <id id={props.match.params.id}/>
         : ""
        }

        <Link to='/primary/one'>Primary with id</Link>
    </div>
)
```

```js
const Routes = () => {
    return(
        <Router>
            <Route exact path='/' component={main} /> 
            <Route exact path='/primary' component={primary} />
            <Route exact path='/primary/:id' component={id} />
        </Router>
    )
}
```

**EDIT**
The below is not tested. Try if this works.

```js
const primary = ({match}) => (
    <div>
        This is the Primary route
        <br/>
        <Link to='/primary/one'>Primary with id</Link>
        {<Route path='/primary/:id' component={id} />}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: But i want 
```
<Route exact path='/primary/:id' component={id} />
```
this route inside primary component.. isn't that possible..?

Comment: Did you mean `primary` component works as a layout for each and every `id` component?

Comment: Since id component is accessed from primary component , I want that route inside primary component rather than in Routes or App component.. It seems that was working on earlier version of react-router-dom. I don't know why this isn't working now.

Comment: That's not working.. I think I have to declare primary route without path.. <Route component={primary} /> ... Now its working..

Answer (score 0):

You just put this code in your routes:

```js
const Routes = () => {
    return(
        <Router>
            <Route exact path='/' component={main} />
            <Route exact path='/primary/:id' component={primary} />    
        </Router>
    )
}
```